# pip3 install timestring

Tags: python3, pip

I am trying to install timestring library into python3.5 on ubuntu 16.04 using the command: pip3 install timestring

Getting this error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 742, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 831, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1032, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 346, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 317, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 241, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pytz-2013b0.dist-info'
```

I am not sure what's exactly wrong.
How can I get the timestring library installed?

Answer (score 1):

It's trying to install in a system directory and your user doesn't have permissions to do that.

You have 2 options:

1. Install locally, usually in a virtualenv. See here: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/
2. Install globally, with sudo so you have root privileges: `sudo pip install timestring`

Personally I prefer option 1, and to keep each project's dependencies isolated in a venv, but that's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the traceback, `pip3` is trying to create a directory in `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages` but it does not have permissions to do so because you probably did not run `pip3` with `sudo`. The best way to install `timestring` though is to avoid `sudo` altogether and use `virtualenv` instead. The following code worked for me:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install virtualenv  # install virtualenv if you haven't
cd ~/<project directory>  # cd to your project directory
virtualenv venv -p python3  # create virtualenv named venv for Python 3
source venv/bin/activate  # activate virtualenv
pip install timestring
```

After you are done with writing code for the project, run `deactivate` to deactivate the virtualenv.